# How to remove some characters form a variable PHP

Tags: php, html

My string looks like this

```
$string_value = /hello/world/this/feels/great/
```

how can I trim world and feels so the output looks like ?

```
$string_value = /hello/this/great/
```

Thanks

Comment: [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: The code you have would not work, strings must be enclosed in single or double quotes. And put a semilocon at the end on line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
$string_value = '/hello/world/this/feels/great/';
$string_value = str_replace( array( 'world/', 'feels/' ), '', $string_value );

echo $string_value;
```

That's the simple way.